# Are there any restrictions for guitar colors?

Tags: copyright

Yellow Ibanez NDM3 has disappeared from manufacturer site and got replaced with NDM4 sunburst one. It is not listed as discontinued model  Did it happen because of law issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions to what colours a manufacturer can and cannot paint. There may be restrictions to what they can call the colours. For example Rickenbacker use the 'glo' suffix with a lot of their colours (think Fireglo, Mapleglo, Jetglo). Whilst fans and collectors tend to add the 'glo' suffix colloquially to other Rickenbacker finishes, notably 'Burgundyglo' or the subtly dysphemismistic 'Glueglo' (used to describe some rare Rickenbacker models with glue bleeding from the binding into the surrounding wood), I don't think another manufacturer could use 'glo' without facing some litigation from Rickenbacker themselves.

The Ibanez NDM3 looks like a homage to Gibson's TV Yellow, of sorts. TV Yellow itself is, rather than a solid colour finish, the result of a bewildering multi-step finishing process involving tinted grain fillers and clear coats. There is a lot of variation in Gibson's TV Yellow, even throughout the period in the '50s in which it was originally used. Therefore I don't see Gibson standardising it to a single hue and then chasing other manufacturers for their visual approximations. Beyond that I cannot think of another manufacturer who could lay claim to that shade of yellow.

The Noodles model is a re-hashed Talman model, and from memory they used to come with some sort of gaffa tape finish. This yellow finish was probably just for a short run, perhaps because the paint was specially commissioned by Ibanez.

Less esoterically, some manufacturers stick to the 'classic' finishes because they know they sell. Black, white and three-tone sunburst are less polarising than obscurer colours, so are always in demand.

Answer (score 3):

Manufacturers frequently change their catalogues according to consumer demand. Probably the yellow model did not sell enough to justify keeping it in the catalogue.